# Determine the components of a cofinite space.

Tags: general-topology

> Determine the components of a cofinite space.

The components are defined to be maximal connected subsets of a space $X$. We also know that the components are closed sets. If we consider the cofinite space $(X, \tau_c)$, then the closed sets are all finite as $U \in \tau_c \iff U^c$ is finite.

I find this slightly problematic since if $X$ is infinite or uncountable, then the components should partition $X$, but if all the components are closed, then they are finite and thus I would have that $X = \bigcup C$, but the lhs of this is infinite or uncountable and rhs is a union of finite sets?

Is it so that the only possible component is the space itself?

Comment: All components are closed, but not all closed sets are components.

Comment: But they are still finite and partition $X$ and thus $X$ would be a union over finite sets. @ArturoMagidin

Comment: No, because there is *another* closed set besides the finite ones...

Comment: The mistake is your claim that $U\in \tau_c\iff U^c$ is finite. You forgot that the topology must also include $\varnothing$ and $X$, so the correct description is "$U\in\tau_c\iff U=\varnothing \text{ or }U^c$ is finite."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ is finite, then the cofinite topology is the discrete topology (every set is open and every set is closed), so the components are the singletons.

If $X$ is infinite, let $U$ and $V$ be nonempty open sets. Then the complement of $U$ is finite, and thus cannot contain an infinite set.  Since $V$ is infinite (being nonempty and having finite complement), we must have that $U\cap V\neq \varnothing$. Thus, any two nonempty open sets intersect in $X$.

In particular, $X$ is connected: for if $U$ and $V$ are open subsets such that $X=U\cup V$ and $U\cap V=\varnothing$, then by the above it must be the case that $U=\varnothing$ or $V=\varnothing$. Thus, $X$ has only one component when $X$ is infinite.

What you forgot is that the whole set is also closed. Your description of the topology is incomplete, since your description excludes $\varnothing$ when $X$ is infinite. The correct description is
$$U\in\tau_c\iff U=\varnothing\text{ or }U^c\text{ is finite.}$$